# Infinite Background problem with division SpriteKit

Tags: swift, background, sprite-kit, frame, updates

I've been trying to implement an infinite background animation, which should change between 4 images of equal height and then repeat the sequence. However, it does not seem to work properly.

Note `anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)`

```swift
func updateBackground(currentTime: TimeInterval){
        var delta: CGFloat = 0.0
        if lastUpdate != nil {
            delta = CGFloat(currentTime - lastUpdate)
        }

        //First increment position
        activeBackground1.position.y += delta*backgroundVelocity
        activeBackground2.position.y += delta*backgroundVelocity

        //Detect bounds surpass
        if activeBackground1.position.y > activeBackground1.size.height + screen.height/2 {
            lastSky = (lastSky + 1)%4
            sky1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "sky" + String(lastSky))
            activeBackground1.texture = sky1
            //Reposition: background1 new position is equal to minus the entire height of
            //background2 + its y size.
            activeBackground1.position.y = -abs(activeBackground2.size.height-activeBackground2.position.y)
        }

        if activeBackground2.position.y > activeBackground2.size.height + screen.height/2 {
            lastSky = (lastSky + 1)%4
            sky1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "sky" + String(lastSky))
            activeBackground2.texture = sky1
            activeBackground2.position.y = -abs(activeBackground1.size.height-activeBackground1.position.y)
        }
    }
```

The update algorithm works fine, but when it is needed to reposition one of the two background, it seems there is an offset of about `10.0 CGFloat` from one background to another. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT: It turned out that the error was located in my image, which presented some blank rows and therefore generated visualisation glitches. So my code works perfectly.**

Comment: On last line activeBackground2 take position relative a modified activeBackground1.posiiton, maybe this is the problem.

Comment: @Maetschl even removing 9.0 does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do the test and most likely you should use something like:

```
activeBackground2.position.y = activeBackground1.size.height + activeBackground1.position.y
```

instead of

```
activeBackground2.position.y = -abs(activeBackground1.size.height-activeBackground1.position.y)
```

I did this example and it works correctly: https://github.com/Maetschl/SpriteKitExamples/tree/master/InfiniteBackground/InfiniteBackground
Feel free to see and use.

[image]

Comment: Thanks in advance. Are you sure your anchorPoint are set as mine? Moreover, does the center of your scene is (0, 0)? I'm checking your code right now for assuring this. I saw no anchorPoint settings

Comment: Center of screen .zero and no anchorPoints configuration for the example.

Comment: I voted you as a solution because your code allowed me to understand that my error was in the image I've used.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is floating point math causing rounding errors.  I am on a phone right now so I can’t wrote code, but what you want to do is have 1 parent SKNode to handle your entire background.

Add your background slivers to the parent node.
You then place the moving action on the parent only.

As each sliver leaves the screen, you take the sliver, and move it to the end of the other slivers.

This jumping should always be done with integer math, leaving no holes.

Basically:
The floating point moving math is done on the parent node.

The integer based tile jumping is done on each of the slivers.

Comment: This turned out not to be the problem in my case, but it is indeed a problem in certain case.